# C# WinForm press tabs and it jumps all over the place

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox, tabs

I have a `WinForm` program.  In one screen it has several `ComboBoxes`, `TextBoxes`, and `Buttons`. How can I make it so that when the user presses `tab`, it will go through the fields in **sequential order**.  Meaning from top to bottom?  Or we can say "In my defined order"?  So, for example, it starts with `TextBox1`, and then when the user presses `Tab`, it will go to the next `TextBox`, and when `Tab` is pressed again, will go to `Button1`, etc. etc.

Not sure if it’s possible, but for some reason pressing tab jumps all over the place.  What defines the "tab"? what logic does it use to make it jump to the next field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each control has a property called `TabIndex`.  When a user presses the Tab key, Windows cycles through each control in the order of the tab index.  If two controls have the same TabIndex, they are selected in the order in which the controls were added to the Forms Controls collection.

It is also worth noting that if you have a control that can contain a group of controls within  it's Controls collection (i.e. GroupBox), the tab processing engine will give tab focus to the parent control and then cycle through all of the internal controls, in their internal sorted order.  This means that all child TabIndex values can be maintained independently of all other controls that are in the same collection as the parent control.

Answer (score 10):

The TabIndex property of each control defines the tab order within a container (Form, GroupBox, Panel, etc).  If you are working in the Visual Studio Designer, you can use the *View --> Tab Order* menu item to view/edit the tab sequence.

Comment: +1 I almost forgot about that feature, it is truly wonderful. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `TabIndex` propert on the control.  Be aware that according to the documentation, you must set the `TabStop` property to `true` in order for it to be included in the tab ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the [`TabIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx) of each control. There is a button in the designer toolbar to make it easier (I don't remember the name, but you should find it easily... it's probably something like "Tab Order"). Click this button, then click each control on the form in turn.

Answer (score 1):

Each control has a property called "TabIndex". These will by default just be incrementing as you create items. You can set these manually.

Answer (score 0):

Set the TabIndex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984423%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx) property.